# Identifying where to export PATH updates in both Mac OSX and Linux, regardless of terminal

Tags: linux, bash, macos, scripting, path

I'm familiar with methods that rely on `.bashrc` across both platforms, but then there's always folks that have ZSH (`.zshrc`), and I'm wondering what the best way to check / identify the place to update a PATH variable permanently is across OSX and Linux, specifically from a Bash script, for at least these two types of terminals. Not sure if I need to do some sort of nested IF THENS, or if something is out there that is kind of elegant. Thanks.

Comment: Ask it in Super User (eventually Server Fault)

Comment: On OS X it's .bashrc_profile

Comment: No, not `.bashrc_profile`, it's `.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

There's a system wide profile at `/etc/profile` that you can use to set variables. Of course, you need root permission to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for bash users and zshell users, with the example in this case of adding miniconda, but you can change the value for `DIRECTORY_TO_APPEND_TO_PATH` pretty easily...

```
update_script_startup_file() {
    DIRECTORY_TO_APPEND_TO_PATH="\$HOME/miniconda/bin"
    echo "if [[ \":\$PATH:\" != *\":$DIRECTORY_TO_APPEND_TO_PATH:\"* ]]; then" >> $STARTUP_FILE
    echo "  export PATH=\"\$PATH:$DIRECTORY_TO_APPEND_TO_PATH\"" >> $STARTUP_FILE
    echo "fi" >> $STARTUP_FILE
}

if [ -n "`$SHELL -c 'echo $BASH_VERSION'`" ]; then
    STARTUP_FILE="$HOME/.bashrc"
    update_script_startup_file
elif [ -n "`$SHELL -c 'echo $ZSH_VERSION'`" ]; then
    STARTUP_FILE="$HOME/.zshrc"
    update_script_startup_file
else
    echo "Couldn't automatically add Miniconda to the PATH of your preferred terminal. We suggest working from Bash or ZShell." 
fi
```

If anyone wants to edit this to add support for other shells, they're most welcome to!